# Using .NET Core Web API as subroute of ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms

I have .NET Framework 4.8 ASP.NET Web Forms application. Using ashx-handlers is quite inconvenient, so I want to use .NET Core Web API (in order to switch all of my code from handlers to controllers and switch the whole app to .NET Core).

I know that attaching ASP.NET WebAPI to ASP.NET Web Forms is [easy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms), but I'm struggling with .NET Core WebAPI, because its request pipeline is different.

Are there any ways to use .NET Core WebAPI project from existing Web Forms app as a subroute?

Comment: You need to bind to an interface, not a class (a form is a class).

Comment: @jdweng The question is not about `DataBind`, it is about using WebAPI and WebForms altogether

Comment: The OP said "Are there any ways to bind".

Comment: @jdweng edited my question to get rid of ambiguity

Comment: It is still an interface issue.  You are probably passing a JSON string and still want to make the interface a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.
Targeting .net framework and .net core is a completely different thing.

I'd create two different applications and I'd use IIS UrlRewrite/ARR to redirect specific requests to the core application:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:44444/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```

in this way, any request directed to /api/ will be forwarded (internally in IIS, not from the client) to another web application listening on port 44444